# Missing Edges in mesh

Tags: modifiers, edges

[image]

Hello - *disclaimer*  still learning blender ...

I'm making a boot, and made the shape using two cylinders and connecting them using a boolean modifier. Somewhere along the way after this, I have noticed that my horizontal edges don't go all the way round the front. When I add a new edge loop, it only add it to the back side of the boot. At this point I'm not sure what to do, so I think I'll start again... but thought I'd see on here if anyone could shine some light...

Should I have used different shapes before the boolean modifier? I also noticed it was quite annoying that I ended up with so many vertices at the connecting point.

Edit: I also noticed that on the front "foot" part of the object, I also can't add an edge loop the whole way round. See in image, I tried to add an edge loop in the middle and it only went through two edges.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join edges so your edge continues around the front, then select the two vertices (start and end) and press <kbd>J</kbd>.

The reason your edge loop does not go all the way around is that not all your faces are quads.

If you are new then I suggest https://topologyguides.com/. Good luck!

Comment: thank you will check it out!